# PHP regex random pattern of 5 characters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to check a license key with a pattern of 5 groups of 5 random letters separated by "-". I would like to verify the following: each group consists of 5 letters, each group does not contact certain letters, and all of the groups are capital letters. I know I can do this with the following, but I believe there is an easier method with a possible single regex expression:

```
$testKey = 'ASDFG-ASDFG-ASDFG-ASDFG-ASDFG';
$testKeyArray = explode('-', $testKey);
$cntKey = count($testKeyArray);
if($cntKey != 5) {
    echo 'Failed';
} else {
    for($x=0;$x<$cntKey;++$x) {
        if(strlen($testKeyArray[$x]) != 5) {
            echo 'Failed';
        }
        if(preg_match("^[B]^",$testKeyArray[$x]) == 1) {
            echo 'Failed';
        }
    }
    echo 'Success';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas

```
^\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}$
```

Will match any alphunumeric characters AND underscores, I believe you want to match just alphabetical characters:

> all of the groups are capital letter

In that case use

```
/^[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}$/
```

Example:

```
$pattern = "/^[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}-[A-Z]{5}$/";
if (preg_match($pattern, "ASDFG-ASDFG-ASDFG-ASDFG-ASDFG")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

> each group does not contact certain letters

If you want it to not contain specific letters, you will need to break up your ranges. For example, if you don't want the letter `C`, your range would be `[A-BD-Z]` instead of `[A-Z]`

Comment: How can I exclude "B" or " B and C" from the pattern?

Comment: To exclude `B` you would use `[AC-Z]`. To exclude `B` and `C` you would use `[AD-Z]`

Comment: Or `/^(?:[A-Z]{5}-){4}[A-Z]{5}$/`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly easy way. Captures and validates in one operation.

2 ways.

- This way is the quickest for just simple class exclusions.

`^(?!.*[B])([A-Z]{5})-([A-Z]{5})-([A-Z]{5})-([A-Z]{5})-([A-Z]{5})$`

Expanded:

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?! .* [B] )                  # Not any of these, add more
 ( [A-Z]{5} )                  # (1)
 -
 ( [A-Z]{5} )                  # (2)
 -
 ( [A-Z]{5} )                  # (3)
 -
 ( [A-Z]{5} )                  # (4)
 -
 ( [A-Z]{5} )                  # (5)
 $                             # EOS
```

- This way is the quickest for complex expressions.

`^((?&ltr){5})-((?&ltr){5})-((?&ltr){5})-((?&ltr){5})-((?&ltr){5})$(?(DEFINE)(?<ltr>(?![B])[A-Z]))`

Expanded:

```
 ^                             # BOS
 ( (?&ltr){5} )                # (1)
 -
 ( (?&ltr){5} )                # (2)
 -
 ( (?&ltr){5} )                # (3)
 -
 ( (?&ltr){5} )                # (4)
 -
 ( (?&ltr){5} )                # (5)
 $                             # EOS 

 (?(DEFINE)
      (?<ltr>                       # (6 start)
           (?! [B] )                     # Not any of these chars ahead, add more
           [A-Z]                         # Single any of A-Z
      )                             # (6 end)
 )
```

Comment: @talsibony - Easy and fast _!!_